# How to execute HTML get method in asynctask?

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask, get

Im trying to pass this method for making a get request and passing the data as a String:

```
public String getdata(String url) throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException {
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            content));
    String con;
    while ((con = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        build.append(con);
    }
    return build.toString();
}
```

into an asynctask because i cant run it in the main thread, I tried to do this but "build" cannot be accessed:

```
    public class getHTTPdata extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    content));
            String con;
            while ((con = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                build.append(con);
            }
            return build.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return build;
    }
}
```

I'd like to access it as:

```
getHTTPdata task = new getHTTPdata();
task.execute("myurl");
```

Thank you.

Comment: `return build;`: Your `StringBuilder` is scoped to your try block, so you won't be able to access it outside of the try block. Seems like you're intending to return null or an empty `String`.

Comment: But do you think I'm making the asynctask class right? I cant understand asynctask very well so im not sure if this is the right way to go or just simply run the first method in the main thread

Comment: Everything looks right except for `HttpGet(url);`. Since the method takes a variable amount of parameters, you need to specify `HttpGet(url[0]);` if you only ever plan on passing in 1 parameter.

Comment: Oh ok thank you man! but if i put the `StringBuilder` out of the try block, the `return build;`  tells me that a String is required instead of StringBuilder any idea how to solve this? again thank you so much i've been dealing with this http get thing for a week

Comment: What are you intending to return if there is an exception?